# changing php user to run as nginx user

Tags: php, nginx, file-permissions

How do I change the user under which php is running? I'm running nginx with php enabled. I would like to change php to run as the same user nginx runs as, is this possible? Is this more secure than leaving it as www-data or apache?

Comment: if you are using php-fpm you can set user in php-fpm.conf

`user=nginx_user`

`group=nginx_group`

Comment: It is more secure to have different user for each virtual site. Even if one of them was hacked they can't access other sites. If php works under same user as nginx all the sites can be accessible if one of them was hacked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, when I add these attributes to php-fpm.conf nginx gives me a 502 with connection refused in the error logs.

Comment: It's the right answer - but your PHP must have permissions to read from the source files. If the only thing you were able to tell  was that you are now getting a 502 error then you have a problem with how your error logging is configured (likely this applies both when running as user=nginx_user and user=www-data). You did check that the value you put in the conf file was the same as the nginx process owner?

Comment: Yep, it is the right answer. I needed to change to the correct nginx process owner, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to change the nginx user, here's what I have done on my VPS to prevent users from accessing stuff other than what they need to.

*assume that there's a user called `myuser` on the server, with a home `/home/myuser` and that we're using php5-fpm for php*

What I did is creating a `www` directory inside his home `/home/myuser/www` and and added `myuser` to the `www-data` group ( I don't remember why this was or is necessary, you can skip the groups part until you find that you do need it ).

For the php process i created a new pool `/etc/php5/fpm/pools.d`, just took a copy of the default `www` and rename it, edit the `pool name` and `user` and socket name in the `listen` directive.

Restart `php5-fpm` and the new pool starts.

Edit the nginx virtual host, make it point to the correct to the new `root` and `fastcgi_pass` to the new socket file

By doing this site now can't write outside it's home and all files uploaded/created by the site will also be under the same user, saved me the hassle of logs under `www-data` and stuff like that.